# How to access the id of another layout in Adapter class?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, android-adapter

I created one Recycler view which is having Adapter class then I have another layout name cart .
I want to access the textview which is present in cart in Adapter class
Iam using LayoutInflater in viewHolder class to access Textview present in cart.xml but it is doing nothing
please Help!

**itemDetailsAdapter java**

```
package com.example.wedeliver;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;
import com.google.android.material.snackbar.Snackbar;
import com.google.firebase.database.ChildEventListener;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class itemDetailsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<itemDetailsAdapter.Viewholder>
{

    public Context context;
    public ArrayList<itemDetails> courseModelArrayList;
    long maxitems=0;
    long booked_items_count=0;
    View view1;

    // Constructor
    public itemDetailsAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<itemDetails> courseModelArrayList) {
        this.context = context;
        this.courseModelArrayList = courseModelArrayList;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public itemDetailsAdapter.Viewholder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        // to inflate the layout for each item of recycler view.
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_display_card, parent, false);
        View view1 = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.cart, parent, false);

        return new Viewholder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull itemDetailsAdapter.Viewholder holder, int position) {
        // to set data to textview and imageview of each card layout
        itemDetails itemDetails = courseModelArrayList.get(position);
        //Context context = holder.product_image.getContext();
        Glide.with(context).load(itemDetails.getImageView()).into(holder.product_image);
       holder.discount.setText(itemDetails.getDiscount()+"% OFF");
        holder.actual_price.setText(itemDetails.getActual_price());
        holder.actual_price.setPaintFlags(holder.actual_price.getPaintFlags() | Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG);
        holder.selling_price.setText("₹ /-"+itemDetails.getSelling_price());
        holder.product_name.setText(itemDetails.getProduct_name());
        holder.product_brand.setText(itemDetails.getProduct_brand());
        maxitems=Long.parseLong(itemDetails.getCapacity().toString());
        booked_items_count=Long.parseLong(itemDetails.getBooked_items_count().toString());
        holder.add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if(booked_items_count<maxitems) {

                   booked_items_count++;
                    holder.counter.setText(""+booked_items_count);
                    notifyDataSetChanged();

                    //databaseReference1.child("booked_items_count").setValue(""+booked_items_count);
                   // Log.d("hello",""+booked_items_count);
                }
                else
                {
                    Snackbar.make(view,"Out of stock",Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
        //Toast.makeText(context,"hello",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
       // DatabaseReference databaseReference1=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Items").child("Item_"+itemDetails.getProduct_name());
       // itemDetails.setBooked_items_count(""+booked_items_count);
       // databaseReference1.setValue(itemDetails);

    }


    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return courseModelArrayList.size();
    }

    public class Viewholder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public ImageView product_image;
        public TextView product_name,product_brand,selling_price,actual_price,discount;
        public TextView add,counter;


        public Viewholder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
           product_image=itemView.findViewById(R.id.product_img);
           product_name=itemView.findViewById(R.id.product_name);
            product_brand=itemView.findViewById(R.id.brand_name);
            selling_price=itemView.findViewById(R.id.selling_price);
            actual_price=itemView.findViewById(R.id.product_price);
            add=itemView.findViewById(R.id.product_add);
            //here Iam inflating the cart layout and accessing the noficationnumber1 id preset in cart
           View view=LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.cart,null);
           counter=view.findViewById(R.id.notificationNumber1) ;

            discount=itemView.findViewById(R.id.discount);
        }
    }
}
```

***cart.xml***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:id="@+id/notificationIcon"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:src="@drawable/cart"/>
    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="18dp"
        android:layout_height="18dp"
        app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/accent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/notificationIcon"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/notificationIcon"
        app:cardCornerRadius="50dp">
        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/notificationNumber1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="1"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.545"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"></TextView>
        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrong way, you return ViewHolder(view), but view1 was not binded, you should youse adapter with multiple viewType.
Check this: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html#getItemViewType(int)

Comment: I want to use only one field that is textview present in cart.xml in adapter class because card is having a textview which is the notification counter which will increase it value when we press add button present in Recycler view

Comment: extract then this textview to separate xml file, and include this layout to necessary layout

Comment: I need to work upon the adapter class and the textfield present in another xml

Answer (score 0):

First you should move cart.xml into activity containing recyclerview. Then create an onClick listener interface in recyclerview adapter and implement that in activity containing cart.xml. Now you can change counter value via that interface inside activity containing cart.xml.

Answer (score 0):

**1)** You should initialize the TextView in your adapter class globally.

```
TextView textView;
```

**2)** Set your **cart.xml** layout in **onCreateViewHolder()** using **LayoutInflater** and assign your textview Id.

```
 // set the custom layout
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    final View customLayout
            = inflater.inflate(
                    R.layout.help_support_dialog_design,
                    null);
    textView = customLayout.findViewById(R.id.txtview);
```

Now, you can do anything with this Textview.